# More pythonic way to iterate in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, scientific-computing

I am an engineering student and I'm accustomed to write code in Fortran, but now I'm trying to get more into Python for my numerical recipes using Numpy.

If I needed to perform a calculation repeatedly using elements from several arrays, the immediate translation from what I'd write in Fortran would be

```
k = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float)
u = ...
M = ...
r = ...
for i in xrange(N):
  k[i] = ... # Something with u[i], M[i], r[i] and r[i - 1], for example
```

But I was wondering if this way is more pythonic, or preferrable in any way:

```
for i, (k_i, u_i, M_i, r_i) in enumerate(zip(k, u, M, r)):
  k_i = ... # Something with u_i, M_i, r_i and r[i - 1]
```

Thanks to enumerate I have the index, otherwise if I don't need it I could use just zip or itertools.izip.

Any ideas? How is the code affected in terms of performance? Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

Almost all numpy operations are performed element-wise. So instead of writing an explicit loop, try defining `k` using an array-based formula:

```
r_shifted = np.roll(x, shift = 1)
k = ... # some formula in terms of u, M, r, r_shifted
```

For example, instead of

```
import numpy as np

N=5
k = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float)
u = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float)
M = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float)
r = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float)
for i in xrange(N):
  k[i] = u[i] + M[i] + r[i] + r[i-1]
print(k)  
# [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  4.]
```

use:

```
r_shifted = np.roll(r, shift = 1)
k = u + M + r + r_shifted
print(k)
# [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  4.]
```

---

[np.roll(r, shift = 1)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) returns a new array of the same size as `r`, with `r_shifted[i] = r[i-1]` for `i = 0, ..., N-1`.

```
In [31]: x = np.arange(5)

In [32]: x
Out[32]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [33]: np.roll(x, shift = 1)
Out[33]: array([4, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Making a copy like this requires more memory (of the same size as `r`) but allows you to do fast numpy operations instead of using a slow Python loop.

---

Sometimes the formula for `k` can instead be defined in terms of `r[:-1]` and `r[1:]`. Note `r[:-1]` and `r[1:]` are slices of `r` and of the same shape.
In this case, you don't need any extra memory since basic slices of `r` are so-called *views* of `r`, not copies.

I didn't define `k` this way in the example above because then `k` would have had length `N-1` instead of `N`, so it would have been slightly different than what your original code would have produced.

Comment: The fact is that it is not always possible to write a formula for the calculations you need: there can be more complicated operations involved, or you may have the arrays initialized to zero and perform successive approaches with some external values. It's the case when trying to solve an ODE, for instance. Anyway, thanks for the np.roll() tip!

Comment: Indeed. If there is no numpy-base function or expression to avoid the Python loop, then you may want to try rewriting the loop in [Cython](http://cython.org/) (See also, "Fast numerical computations with Cython" [600K PDF](http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/SciPy2009/paper_2/full_text.pdf)).

Comment: There is also [F2py](http://www.scipy.org/F2py), which allows you call Fortran functions from Python. Then you wouldn't have to translate your code at all.

Comment: I was already aware of f2py, I wanted to write my code in Python; but Cython is a good idea too, it takes advantages from both sides.

Answer (score -1):

I like list comprehensions

```
k = [ x ** y for x, y in zip(some_array, some_other_array) ]
```

others like `map`

```
map( lambda x, y : x*y , zip(some_array, some_other_array) )
```

will  multiply two arrays and return you a list or generator.  (Of course you there are other ways of doing that particular task in numpy.)   If you want to convert it back to an array, you can do

k = array( [ x ** y for x, y in zip(some_array, some_other_array) ] )

Comment: The fact is that, with this approach, you cannot recover a previous element, for example (that's why I was using enumerate, as shown)

Comment: Quite right.  When I have complicated operations to do on sequences I sometimes write a stand-alone function generator that explicitly yields the results.  Then my calling code can pack it up in a numpy array if it wants.

Comment: -1, because the prefered way in numpy are element-wise operations. see answer by unutbu